# Change JSON output with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Im working with an API using Node. With node I'm able to get a list of data.
When i Use Stringify i get something like this :

```
{ totalNumEntries: 700,
  entries:
   [ { data:
        [ { key: 'KEYWORD_TEXT',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'StringAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'StringAttribute',
               value: 'red herring 9e23f4ad' } },
          { key: 'SEARCH_VOLUME',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'LongAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'LongAttribute',
               value: '4574730' } } ] },
     { data:
        [ { key: 'KEYWORD_TEXT',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'StringAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'StringAttribute',
               value: 'nike 656e95f0' } },
          { key: 'SEARCH_VOLUME',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'LongAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'LongAttribute',
               value: '3442386' } } ] },
     { data:
        [ { key: 'KEYWORD_TEXT',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'StringAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'StringAttribute',
               value: 'red herring 2bb32682' } },
          { key: 'SEARCH_VOLUME',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'LongAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'LongAttribute',
               value: '2641524' } } ] },
     { data:
        [ { key: 'KEYWORD_TEXT',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'StringAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'StringAttribute',
               value: 'nike d4b589f6' } },
          { key: 'SEARCH_VOLUME',
            value:
             { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'LongAttribute' },
               'Attribute.Type': 'LongAttribute',
               value: '4778937' } } ] },
```

My problem now is. I want Key-value pairs of data for example :

```
[
  {
    "KEYWORD_TEXT": "red herring 9e23f4ad",
    "SEARCH_VOLUME": 4574730
  },
  {
    "KEYWORD_TEXT": "nike 656e95f0",
    "SEARCH_VOLUME": 3442386
  },
  etc...
]
```

In my code I have tried the next :

```
targetingIdeaService.get({selector: selector}, function (error, result) {
var resultaten = result;
console.log(resultaten.entries[0]);

})
```

The output of this was close to what i wanted but not exactly. Here is what I'm getting:

```
{ data:
   [ { key: 'KEYWORD_TEXT', value: [Object] },
     { key: 'COMPETITION', value: [Object] },
     { key: 'SEARCH_VOLUME', value: [Object] } ] }
```

As you can see the key is beign shown but the value is still an object. I would like the above data to be the same except i want the value to be shown too.

Comment: the value _is_ an object...

Comment: Yes but i want to display what is inside of it @LucaKiebel

Comment: what is `targetingIdeaService.get` doing?

Comment: you could use `JSON.stringify` on your JSON Object and console.log that

Comment: Its the function that retrieves all the results. I dont think its relevant in this case, you should look inside that function at resultaten thats where i can select specific data.@Vanojx1

Comment: if you are logging into node cmd it dont show nested object, just show "Object" but your value its correct i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use [[].map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array with the results. Here is an example...

```
var newResult = resultaten.entries.map(function(entry) {
    var result = {};

    entry.data.forEach(function (datum) {
        result[datum.key] = datum.value.value;
    })

    return result;
})
```

Your value is there, I think `console.log` just show `[Object]` instend of the detail value for netsted objects.

Comment: it does from a certain depth.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ls = {
  "totalNumEntries": 700,
  "entries": [{
    "data": [{
      "key": "KEYWORD_TEXT",
      "value": {
        "attributes": {
          "xsi:type": "StringAttribute"
        },
        "Attribute.Type": "StringAttribute",
        "value": "red herring 9e23f4ad"
      }
    }, {
      "key": "SEARCH_VOLUME",
      "value": {
        "attributes": {
          "xsi:type": "LongAttribute"
        },
        "Attribute.Type": "LongAttribute",
        "value": "4574730"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "key": "KEYWORD_TEXT",
      "value": {
        "attributes": {
          "xsi:type": "StringAttribute"
        },
        "Attribute.Type": "StringAttribute",
        "value": "nike 656e95f0"
      }
    }, {
      "key": "SEARCH_VOLUME",
      "value": {
        "attributes": {
          "xsi:type": "LongAttribute"
        },
        "Attribute.Type": "LongAttribute",
        "value": "3442386"
      }
    }]
  }]
};
// stringified
var newList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ls.entries.length; i++) {
  var obj = ls.entries[i];
  var newObj = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < obj.data.length; j++) {
    var contnt = obj.data[j];
    newObj[contnt.key] = contnt.value.value;
  }
  newList.push(newObj);
}
console.log(newList)
```

I have taken a part of json data from your question. please check wether you are looking for this.

Comment: You made a variable out of the data that i put in the question. But this data is not always the same.

Comment: what about you json structure? will it remain same always?

Comment: This structure can change too.

Comment: @Kevin.a : Then i am sorry. This solution wont work. Lets wait for some expert solutions from others.